# Python+mysql - building insert statements in for loop

Tags: python, mysql, loops, for-loop, insert

The following prints the results properly but no records show up in the mysql table I'm attempting to populate:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb
import string

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                    user="user",
                    passwd="******",
                    db="test")
cur=db.cursor()

i = 0

for lt in string.ascii_lowercase:

  dbinsert = """insert into dns(domain,A,MX,T,serial,ttl)
  values('"""+lt+""".com',' 1.1.1."""+str(i)+"""\\n','10 mx1.somehost.com.\\n',
  '@ "txt data"\\n',2013092001,300)"""
  print dbinsert
  i+=1
  #cur=db.cursor()
  try:
    cur.execute(dbinsert)
    db.commit
  except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print e[0], e[1]
    db.rollback()

db.close()
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: PEP 8 (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), that's for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.commit` should be `db.commit()`